# rich:popupPanel form remembering old values

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I have a JSF page powered by a session-based backing bean. The page also includes a rich:popupPanel modal window which contains a form with couple of cascading  elements and a couple of text boxes. The first time I input values into the form and press the Cancel button, the popup disappears. But when I click on the commandButton which displays the popup again, the drop-downs and input text boxes show the previously input values, even though I reset the underlying properties in the backing bean. It is as though the JSF UI elements' state is being cached, because for debugging purposes I print the underlying property values at the bottom of the popup and those are null (or empty).

Why is this happening and is there an effective way to reset the form UI elements' state?

Answer (score 1):

Showing and hiding is just flipping between visible and invisible state. You need to rerender the popup every time you open it if you want it to use the current values.

Edit: Sample code

```
<a4j:commandButton render="popupPanelId" execute="@this"
    oncomplete="#{rich:component('popupPanelId'}.show()" value="Click me" />
```

Comment: How do I re-render? Can you please post some sample code? Thanks.

Comment: @WebUser, you use the `render` attribute. I've added a sample.

Comment: I already had the `render` attribute, but it is somehow pulling the old values even though the backing bean no longer has those values.

Comment: In that case you may want to post a sample of your code. And use `<a4j:log>` to see what response is coming from the server.

Comment: Adding `<f:ajax resetValues="true" />` inside `<a4j:commandButton />` tag helped reset the input values. Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: Ah, are you getting a validation failure? Otherwise you shouldn't need to use @resetValues.